# BeautifulSoup неправильно загружает страницу

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Я хочу получить таблицу с сайта: https://mai.ru/education/schedule/detail.php?group=%D0%9C3%D0%9E-106%D0%91-19

Код

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

base_url = 'https://mai.ru/education/schedule/detail.php?group=%D0%9C3%D0%9E-106%D0%91-19'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'}

session = requests.Session()
request = session.get(base_url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(request.content, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'sc-container'})

print(tables[1])
```

По идее, должен вывходить что-то подобное:

```html
<div class="sc-container">
        <div class="sc-table sc-table-day">
            <div class="sc-table-row">
                <div class="sc-table-col sc-day-header sc-gray">04.09<span class="sc-day">Ср</span></div>

                <div class="sc-table-col sc-table-detail-container">
                    <div class="sc-table sc-table-detail">

                        <div class="sc-table-row">  
                            <!--<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-order"></div>-->
                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-time">10:45 – 12:15</div>
                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-period"></div>
                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-type">ЛК</div>
                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-title">
                                <div class="sc-item-title-body">
                                <span class="sc-title">Химия</span>

                                <br><a href="/education/schedule/ppc.php?guid=3c024137-1d9b-11e0-9baf-1c6f65450efa"><span class="sc-lecturer">Окорокова Надежда Сергеевна</span></a>                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">&nbsp;</span>3-Зал "А"</div>
                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location-icon hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="sc-table-row">  
                            <!--<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-order"></div>-->
                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-time">13:00 – 14:30</div>
                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-period"></div>
                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-type">ПЗ</div>
                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-title">
                                <div class="sc-item-title-body">
                                <span class="sc-title">Физика</span>

                                                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">&nbsp;</span>ГУК Б-552</div>
                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location-icon hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="sc-table-row">  
                            <!--<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-order"></div>-->
                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-time">14:45 – 16:15</div>
                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-period"></div>
                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-type">ЛК</div>
                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-title">
                                <div class="sc-item-title-body">
                                <span class="sc-title">Линейная алгебра и аналитическая геометрия</span>

                                <br><a href="/education/schedule/ppc.php?guid=565d9619-1d9b-11e0-9baf-1c6f65450efa"><span class="sc-lecturer">Дорохов Виктор Михайлович</span></a>                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">&nbsp;</span>ГУК Б-460</div>
                            <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location-icon hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></div>
                        </div>
                                            </div>
                </div>



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Но на деле выводит это:

```html
<div class="sc-container">
<div class="sc-table sc-table-day">
<div class="sc-table-row">
<div class="sc-table-col sc-day-header sc-gray">04.09<span class="sc-day">Ср</span></div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-table-detail-container">
<div class="sc-table sc-table-detail">
<div class="sc-table-row">
<!--<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-order"></div>-->
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-time">10:45 – 12:15</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-period"></div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-type">ЛК</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-title">
<div class="sc-item-title-body">
<span class="sc-title">Химия</span>
<br><a href="/education/schedule/ppc.php?guid=3c024137-1d9b-11e0-9baf-1c6f65450efa"><span class="sc-lecturer">Окорокова Надежда Сергеевна</span></a></br></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Причем если вместо `print(tables[1])` написать `print(tables[0])`, то вывод будет нормальный(как и некоторые другие элементы). Т.е. bs4 периодически выводит правильный(ожидаемый) результат, а иногда и неправильный(неожиданный).

Куда пропадает остальная часть? Почему внезапно теги закрываются? Как это исправить?

Comment: bs4 не выполняет джаваскрипт, поэтому часть страницы не рендерится. Исправить можно, отрендерив страницу в браузере, к примеру, используя selenium.

Comment: Не похоже. Почему тогда другие элементы, которые идут позже иногда отображаются правильно? Да и если вывести всю страницу print(soup), то видно, что она загружено полностью, правда искажённо.

Comment: _Не похоже_ - почему? Чистая `detail.php` в хроме так и рендерится: https://imgur.com/a/cqfPDRM, остальное дорисовывает js + css на стороне браузера. _Почему тогда другие элементы_ - сложно сказать, веб-программист так решил, видимо. _видно, что она загружено полностью, правда искажённо._ - ну я не реверсинжинирил скрипты на странице, но предполагаю, что где-то элементы режутся в одном поддереве и прицепляются в другое; почему, тоже только автору известно.

Comment: Посмотрел как рендерится страница: там как раз то, что мне необходимо. Вся нужная информация. JS только косметику добавляет, а все необходимые элементы появляются сразу. Может мою проблему можно решить как-то иначе? Например выкачать страницу полностью без JS. Если это возможно, то подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в качестве парсера использовать [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/installation.html). Вроде бы с ним все парсится нормально.

```
In [40]: soup = bs(request.content, 'lxml')

In [41]: tables = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'sc-container'})

In [42]: tables[1]
Out[42]: 
<div class="sc-container">
<div class="sc-table sc-table-day">
<div class="sc-table-row">
<div class="sc-table-col sc-day-header sc-gray">04.09<span class="sc-day">Ср</span></div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-table-detail-container">
<div class="sc-table sc-table-detail">
<div class="sc-table-row">
<!--<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-order"></div>-->
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-time">10:45 – 12:15</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-period"></div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-type">ЛК</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-title">
<div class="sc-item-title-body">
<span class="sc-title">Химия</span>
<br/><a href="/education/schedule/ppc.php?guid=3c024137-1d9b-11e0-9baf-1c6f65450efa"><span class="sc-lecturer">Окорокова Надежда Сергеевна</span></a> </div>
</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"> </span>3-Зал "А"</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location-icon hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="sc-table-row">
<!--<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-order"></div>-->
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-time">13:00 – 14:30</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-period"></div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-type">ПЗ</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-title">
<div class="sc-item-title-body">
<span class="sc-title">Физика</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"> </span>ГУК Б-552</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location-icon hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="sc-table-row">
<!--<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-order"></div>-->
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-time">14:45 – 16:15</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-period"></div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-type">ЛК</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-title">
<div class="sc-item-title-body">
<span class="sc-title">Линейная алгебра и аналитическая геометрия</span>
<br/><a href="/education/schedule/ppc.php?guid=565d9619-1d9b-11e0-9baf-1c6f65450efa"><span class="sc-lecturer">Дорохов Виктор Михайлович</span></a> </div>
</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"> </span>ГУК Б-460</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location-icon hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```